# Regex pattern to parse string

Tags: c++, regex, qt

So I need to find a regex to parse a few different cases with the same regex.

First case:

```
Type(arg1, arg2)
```

I need to get `Type`, `arg1`, and `arg2` out of this string.

Second Case:

```
Type(arg1, arg2, ...) (the number of args is variable)
```

I need to get `Type`, `arg1`, `arg2`, and every other arg.

Third Case:

```
Type(arg1 + arg2) or Type(arg1 - arg2) or (lets just say that it can take really any form)
```

Here I need `Type` and `arg1 + arg2`

Note: I'm not opposed to using two regex, meaning if I could get "Type" and anything inside the parenthesis with one regex and then pulling the comma separated args apart using a second regex that would be ok, just not preferred.

Comment: What language are you using? Where is your code that you have tried thus far? http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285733/should-give-me-a-regex-that-does-x-questions-be-closed

Comment: Maybe something like `([a-zA-Z\d+ ]+)` then use `trim` (if available, without a language hard to say) will there ever be other things in the string?

Comment: I'm using Qt 5.7, C++.

Comment: currently this regex: \w+\([\w+,\s]+?\) will validate the expression

Comment: using something simple like (\w+) will satisfy case 1 and 2 but not case 3

Comment: @chris85 case 3 can have anything in it not just +.  it can have words, other symbols, ect.

Comment: As long as it doesn't have `()` in it and `,`s are only for separating the character class should suffice (add whatever other characters are needed). The `,`s and `() `will break each term.

Comment: If it can really take `any form` then you can't use a regex.

Comment: @JAndrewMcCormick I've updated the answer with two patterns, one to define the possible characters and the other to match whatever string not having `(`, `)`, `,`, `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex like:

```
(\w+\s*[+-]?\s*\w+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ycpfw2/3)**

Update: if you pattern can take whatever form, then you can use this pattern:

```
([^(),\n]+)
```

The idea is to match whatever thing except parentheses, commas and new lines

Comment: That won't capture "arg1 + arg2"

Comment: @JAndrewMcCormick i've updated the answer, fixed now.

Comment: that does solve all the cases I listed.  I made a mistake not clarifying case 3.  It can take many different forms.  question will be updated momentarily

Comment: @JAndrewMcCormick I've updated the answer again to support whatever string except few cases